# Why is Apache / PHP suddenly returning the request parameters in my JSON response?

Tags: php, json, apache

My Mac/Apache/PHP script has been correctly returning JSON responses, from a MySql database search, for months. But after placing the PHP script on a new Mac Mini, the HTTPrequest parameters are suddenly being included at the beginning of the JSONresponse.

For example: Initially I was receiving the JSON formatted as such:

```
[{"last_name":"value", "first_name":"value"}]
```

Now, after moving to new version of Apache and PHP I'm getting:

```
{"cmd":"GET", "record_id":"123"} [{"last_name":"value", "first_name":"value"}]
```

I was able to trim off the leading request data, from the JSONResponse, but would prefer to see if anyone knows what caused this and if there is an Apache or PHP configuration that I can adjust to remove it?

Old Apache: 2.2.22
New Apache: 2.2.24

Old PHP: 5.3.15 (w/ suhosin)
New PHP  5.4.17

Comment: This may be something with configuration, but it is your code, so you should find where the output starts and why instead of trying to hide it.